# Time travel book series with a shark sky pirate and a group who call themselves emperors

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel

I’m looking for a specific book series I read a while ago. It’s about a boy who time travels to save his sister. From the bits I can remember he meets a shark sky pirate infected with a parasite and traps a god like figure on the dying earth in the last book. One of the books also consists of him fighting a group calling themselves emperors with one called the pigeon emperor and another the firefinch emperor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [*The Nine Emperors*](https://www.hachettechildrens.co.uk/titles/david-logan/the-nine-emperors/9781780875804/) by David Logan.

> Junk has jumped through space and time to find his sister Ambeline. She has been taken to a country ruled by the nine emperors. Junk and his friends Garvan and Lasel set off to find her. On his quest, Junk will fight off lions, morph into a cyborg, discover the secret of the universe, and play with time itself. Join Junk on an adventure full of humour and heart-pounding action.

It mentions several "emperors" including this one;

> Boo chosea bird native to Nigeria, where he was from, called himself the **Firefinch Emperor**